# How to terminate Python background processes when the calling Bash script is interrupted

Tags: python, python-3.x, bash, sudo, terminate-handler

I have a Python script (`test.py`) like the following:

```py
try:
    while True:
        print("test: {}".format(argv[1]))
    
        time.sleep(1)
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print("process terminated!")
```

So I can stop the program by typing Ctrl-c.

Now I need to execute multiple `test.py` instances with different arguments.
So I am using a Bash script to run multiple Python invocations in parallel like the following:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

export PYENV="/home/AA/.venv/env1/bin/python3"

cd /home/AA/test
sudo $PYENV test.py 1 &
sudo $PYENV test.py 2 &

wait
```

The question is:
when I want to terminate the processes (including the Python processes) by typing "ctrl+C", it's not working.

How can I terminate these background processes by typing "ctrl+C"?

Answer (score 0):

This does not activate the exception when pressing CTRL-C, but maybe it is good enough:

```
export PYENV="/home/AA/.venv/env1/bin/python3"

cd /home/AA/test
doit() { sudo $PYENV test.py "$1"; }
export -f doit

parallel -u doit ::: 1 2
```